# Finding Phase difference between voltage and current

Tags: phase

I have Voltage and current readings which are about 100000 data points. Both voltage and current here are sinusoids which are phase offset and Current leads the voltage.

These two waves don't exactly begin at origin. To find the Phase difference at each data point, I used the formula for *Dot product* that's

$$\phi = \arccos\left(V\cdot \frac{I}{|V|\cdot|I|}\right)$$

Here $V$ and $I$ in the formula indicates the voltage and current at each data point.

- Am I correct?
- and If I am wrong please correct me and tell me a method with which I can accurately find the Phase difference at each point in time domain.

Comment: Two sinusoids can have a phase difference, but not at each datapoint...

Comment: the formatting and structure of your question were frankly an offense. Please put a little more effort in structuring questions next time.

Comment: @CMDoolittle weeeeeell that's not totally true. You can't read the phase of a *sine* from its instantaneous value, but for a *sinusoid*, which might be the ubiquitous $s(t) = e^{j\phi}$, phase is pretty clearly simply the $\angle s$.

Comment: Nevertheless, OP doesn't deal with complex currents or voltages (or he's forgotten that he does, and his question is even more confused), so yes, there's no clear instantaneous voltage. $\frac I{|I|}\equiv \text{sgn} (I) \forall I \in \mathbb R$. Same goes for $\frac V{|V|}$, and thus, obviously, due to linearity $\frac{V\cdot I}{|V| \cdot |I|} \equiv 1$, and the $\arccos$ and thus $\phi$ will always be 0 with OP's formula.

Comment: Based on my understanding Phase difference can be found by finding the difference between points where the voltage and current waveforms intersect the x-axis or by looking at same point between each of the waveforms and seeing the phase difference between them. Please correct me if I am wrong and which would be a reliable formula or method to calculate the Phase difference between Voltage and current signals ?

Comment: What do zero crossings have to do with the way you used vector representations of your voltage and current? Clarification request: are your samples real- or complex-valued, each? if they're complex valued, how did you get those?

Comment: My samples are real values.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the Fourier Transform of both signals and it will immediately reveal your phase difference:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1(t)&=A_1\cos(2\pi f_0t+\phi_1) &x_2(t)&=A_2\cos(2\pi f_0t+\phi_2)\\
X_1(f)&=\frac{A_1}{2}(\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0))\exp(j2\pi f\frac{\phi_1}{2\pi f_0})&X_2(f)&=\frac{A_1}{2}(\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0))\exp(j2\pi f\frac{\phi_2}{2\pi f_0})
\end{align}
$$

Hence, evaluating the Fourier Transform at the frequency of the sinosoid yields
$$
\begin{align}
X_1(f_0)&=\frac{A_1}{2}\delta(0)\exp(j\phi_1) & \arg X_1(f_0)=\phi_1\\
X_2(f_0)&=\frac{A_2}{2}\delta(0)\exp(j\phi_2) & \arg X_1(f_0)=\phi_2
\end{align}
$$

Hence, the phase difference between the sinosoids is just phase difference between the Fourier Transforms at the frequency of the sinosoids. For a real system, you can perform DFT and evaluate the phase at the bin that is most closely to the actual frequency.

If you want to do the calculation in the time domain, you can resort to line 3 of Table 1 in  [this](http://dspguru.com/sites/dspguru/files/Sum_of_Two_Sinusoids.pdf) reference. Let $\phi_1=0$ and calculate the sum of both signals:

$$
x_1(t) + x_2(t) = \sqrt{A_1^2+A_2^2+2A_1A_2\cos(\phi_2)} cos(2\pi f_0 t+\Delta_\phi).
$$

From the amplitude $A$ of the resulting waveform, you can calculate the phase difference:

$$
\cos(\phi_2) = \frac{A^2-A_1^2-A_2^2}{2A_1A_2}
$$

Comment: Good answer! The stress here must be on the fact that there needs to be data for the DFT; you can't do a (useful) DFT on a single sample, you need a vector of these. In OP's special case, a discrete cosine transform would probably be better – I still doubt there's complex signals involved.

Comment: Right, you need several samples to describe the phase difference between two sine waves. A single sample is ambiguous, as it does not describe which time in the wave it corresponds to. Cosine transform is also possible here, though I think the Fourier Transform wider known.

Comment: My data involves hundreds of samples which are real values. In the frequency domain I used the Fourier analysis tool on excel to find the phase difference. It does the FFT on the data. Converts the real values into rectangular form (x+iy). from this we have amplitude given as √(x^2+y^2) and phase difference is given as ϕ=arctan(y/x). In the time domain I used the formulas V=Vm sinωt and I=Im sin(ωt+ϕ) and solved for ϕ which didn't give me sensible values for phase difference. Please suggest any reliable method to find Phase difference in time domain.

Comment: I have added a method to do it in the time domain, via the sum of both signals.